# can we use groupBy filter on child property?

Tags: angularjs, group-by, ngtable

I am using ngTable to  generate a grouped table.

i have some json like

{
Id: 2,
Name: "Sam",
Age: "12",
School: {
 Id: 1,
 City: "Pittsburgh",
 Name: "Abc Public",
 }
}

can i do

```
groupBy: 'School.City'
```

in order to see expand collapse pan based on City ?

i altered the code below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NLgwWr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a string you can use a function

```
groupBy: function(item) {
    return item.School.City;
},
```

See [code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AGqdbjBfEsekIyomPvw3?p=preview)